# How to prove fractal is differentiable at no point?

Tags: real-analysis, fractals

this is a problem from Elementary Classical Analysis. Author constructs a function which is continuous everywhere but is differentiable at no point, and i don't how to prove the second result. Here is the problem:
Construct a function $g(x)$ by letting $g(x)=|x|$ if $x\in [\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ and extending g so that it becomes periodic. Define $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(4^{n-1}x)}{4^{n-1}}$
I know could use Weierstrass M test to prove the first result, but I can't prove that this function is differentiable at no point. Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: Can’t you use uniform continuity to differentiate inside the series? Then you have a divergent series.

Comment: What do you mean about uniform continuity? My original thought is to use the definition to prove it but maybe some terms would cancel out.

Comment: There is an excellent survey of the elementary properties (including differentiablity) of this function, called the *Takagi function*, on [the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1691).

Comment: oh, i see it. Thank you.